# Where are files that are created with rootles systemd/quadlet stored?

Tags: systemd, mysql, podman

I was playing around and following [this guide](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/quadlet-podman) to see if I could spin up a container at startup. I am now done with it and have removed the `systemd` service from `$HOME/.config/containers/systemd/` but I'd like to clean up the files created by the service (i.e. database folder/files). The problem, however, is that I do not know *where* the files have been created. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**mysqld.container**

```ini
[Unit]
Description=MySQL Container
After=local-fs.target

[Container]
Image=docker.io/library/mysql:latest
Environment=MYSQL_DATABASE=dat2000 MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password MYSQL_USER=user MYSQL_PASSWORD=password TZ=Etc/UTC

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target default.target
```

**Commands used:**

```bash
systemctl daemon-reload --user
systemctl start --user mysqld.service
systemctl stop --user mysqld.service
systemctl daemon-reload --user
```